# Swift Compiler is attempting to compile ObjC

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been digging into Swift since last night and I've encountered something strange. I have included a few ObjC classes in my Swift project -- making use of the Bridging Header. However, when I attempt to build the project, the Swift compiler complains because, by all appearances, it is attempting to compile the ObjC code. Is there a step I'm missing here? Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution?

I have scoured the docs, to no avail.

Comment: This has also been cross-posted to the Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/971854#971854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a silly oversight on my part. Many third-party ObjC libraries/code **do not** include Foundation -- assuming it would already be present. Of course, in Swift, this is not the case.

Once I added `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to my imported header, all was well.